# MIFARE DESFire EV2 - How to run command InitializeKeySet

Tags: smartcard, mifare, contactless-smartcard

How to run MIFARE DESFire EV2 command InitializeKeySet (`void initializeKeySet(byte ikeySetNo,DESFireEV1.KeyType ksType`)?

I get an exception like "Invalid keynumber specified" (error code 0x7E).

Comment: (AFAIK) Error code `0x7E` means `LENGTH_ERROR`.

Comment: vlp .. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @vlp  Now I get a different exception which is :0xA0(Requested application ID not found).
Though I have created an application the InitializeKeySet command throws an exception like this.

Comment: @vlp Did you manage to get the InitializeKeySet command working? I also just keep on getting the 0x7E result.

Comment: Hey jacques, it's been a while that i don't work with MIFARE DESFire.I worked on that at my last job.